# How to parse XML attributes with parent attribute into data frame in R

Tags: r, xml, xpath

I am trying to parse an XML file nodes and attributes. Within the file there is a set of nodes with attributes. Nested XML structure is similar to a data frame with a I want to parse this into a data frame.

Here is an example file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TrackMate version="3.8.0">
  <Model spatialunits="µm" timeunits="sec">
    <AllTracks>
      <Track name="Track_2" TRACK_ID="2" NUMBER_SPOTS="140" NUMBER_GAPS="0" >
        <Edge SPOT_SOURCE_ID="960769" SPOT_TARGET_ID="960778" LINK_COST="0.08756957830926632" />
        <Edge SPOT_SOURCE_ID="958304" SPOT_TARGET_ID="958308" LINK_COST="1.4003359672950089" />
        <Edge SPOT_SOURCE_ID="958316" SPOT_TARGET_ID="958322" LINK_COST="1.6985623204008202" />
      </Track>
      <Track name="Track_145" TRACK_ID="145" NUMBER_SPOTS="141" NUMBER_GAPS="0" >
        <Edge SPOT_SOURCE_ID="961623" SPOT_TARGET_ID="961628" LINK_COST="2.2678642015413755" />
        <Edge SPOT_SOURCE_ID="962122" SPOT_TARGET_ID="962127" LINK_COST="38.20777704254654" />
        <Edge SPOT_SOURCE_ID="961869" SPOT_TARGET_ID="961873" LINK_COST="0.2895609647324684" />
      </Track>
    </AllTracks>
  </Model>
</TrackMate>
```

I would like like create a data frame with all attributes of edges and parent's TRACK_ID attribute. I can readily create the data frame with all the edges' attributes with this:

```
edges = data.frame(t(data.frame(xml_attrs(xml_find_all(xmlDoc, xpath = paste0('/TrackMate/Model/AllTracks//Edge'))))))
row.names(edges) = NULL
```

But then the corresponding track ID is lost. I can solve this with a for loop but that is often not the "R way". I was wondering if, there are is a simpler solution? (e.g. with xpath query).

So the final desired output would be this data frame:
[image: output data frame]

Edit: this comes closer but the then Track nodes and Edge nodes are mixed within a list.

```
xml_find_all(xmlDoc, xpath = paste0('/TrackMate/Model/AllTracks//Edge | /TrackMate/Model/AllTracks/Track'))
```

Comment: this is not very hard using xpath.. but please add desired output to your question...

Comment: Sorry, I added the desired output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'trick' is to get a list of alle the edge-nodes, and work with `xpath` from there... You can select the Trach-node from each Edge-node using the `ancestor` from `xpath`.

**libraries used**

```
#load libraries
library( xml2 )
library( magrittr )
```

**sample data**

```
doc <- read_xml('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <TrackMate version="3.8.0">
    <Model spatialunits="µm" timeunits="sec">
      <AllTracks>
      <Track name="Track_2" TRACK_ID="2" NUMBER_SPOTS="140" NUMBER_GAPS="0" >
        <Edge SPOT_SOURCE_ID="960769" SPOT_TARGET_ID="960778" LINK_COST="0.08756957830926632" />
          <Edge SPOT_SOURCE_ID="958304" SPOT_TARGET_ID="958308" LINK_COST="1.4003359672950089" />
            <Edge SPOT_SOURCE_ID="958316" SPOT_TARGET_ID="958322" LINK_COST="1.6985623204008202" />
              </Track>
              <Track name="Track_145" TRACK_ID="145" NUMBER_SPOTS="141" NUMBER_GAPS="0" >
                <Edge SPOT_SOURCE_ID="961623" SPOT_TARGET_ID="961628" LINK_COST="2.2678642015413755" />
                  <Edge SPOT_SOURCE_ID="962122" SPOT_TARGET_ID="962127" LINK_COST="38.20777704254654" />
                    <Edge SPOT_SOURCE_ID="961869" SPOT_TARGET_ID="961873" LINK_COST="0.2895609647324684" />
                      </Track>
                      </AllTracks>
                      </Model>
                      </TrackMate>')
```

**code**

```
#find all edge nodes
edge.nodes <- xml_find_all( doc, ".//Edge")
#build the data.frame
data.frame( TRACK_ID = xml_find_first( edge.nodes, ".//ancestor::Track") %>% xml_attr("TRACK_ID"),
            SPOT_SOURCE_ID = edge.nodes %>% xml_attr("SPOT_SOURCE_ID"),
            SPOT_TARGET_ID = edge.nodes %>% xml_attr("SPOT_TARGET_ID"),
            LINK_COST = edge.nodes %>% xml_attr("LINK_COST") )
```

**output**

```
#   TRACK_ID SPOT_SOURCE_ID SPOT_TARGET_ID           LINK_COST
# 1        2         960769         960778 0.08756957830926632
# 2        2         958304         958308  1.4003359672950089
# 3        2         958316         958322  1.6985623204008202
# 4      145         961623         961628  2.2678642015413755
# 5      145         962122         962127   38.20777704254654
# 6      145         961869         961873  0.2895609647324684
```

Comment: @Parfait Good to remember! But since the pipes in my answer provide better readable code (and thus code that is easier to maintain/review, at least: for me ;-) ), I leave them in.

Comment: This is very readable AND allows me now to find even more complicated solutions on my own.